# insert data from multiple table into a table

Tags: sql

multiple tables don't have any relation or keys and they are not in a same database and we wanna insert their columns into a table.
for example :
 source tables are: [aDB].[aaTable] and [bDB].[bbTable] 
 and destination table is : [cDB].[ccTable]

Comment: Don't you mean that you want to insert rows into the destination table?

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle you can do something like :

```
Insert into [cDB].[ccTable] select * from [aDB].[aaTable];
Insert into [cDB].[ccTable] select * from [bDB].[bbTable];
```

You can put all insert statements like these in a .sql file and then run it from sqlplus

Comment: This will work only if the attributes of the source and destination table are the same (number and type).

Answer (score 0):

```
insert 
  into ccTable(c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, etc...)
        select c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, etc...
          from aaTable
     union all
        select c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, etc...
          from bbTable
```